# Showing existence of limit of a sequence

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Consider the real-valued random variable $X$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$. Consider a sequence of positive real numbers $\{\epsilon_n\}_n$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\epsilon_n=0$. How can I show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(X<\epsilon_n)$ exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $\epsilon_{n}>0$ we have $P\left(X\leq0\right)\leq P\left(X\leq\epsilon_{n}\right)$.

Consequently proving that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P\left(X\leq\epsilon_{n}\right)=P\left(X\leq0\right)$
is in fact the same as showing that for each $\delta>0$ some integer
$n_{\delta}$ exists with $n\geq n_{\delta}\implies P\left(X\leq\epsilon_{n}\right)\leq P\left(X\leq0\right)+\delta$

$\left(0,\infty\right)=\left(1,\infty\right)\cup\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k+1},\frac{1}{k}\right]$
and these sets are disjoint. Consequently:

$$P\left(X>0\right)=P\left(X>1\right)+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}P\left(\frac{1}{k}<X\leq\frac{1}{k-1}\right)=$$$$\lim_{m\to\infty}P\left(X>1\right)+\sum_{k=2}^{m}P\left(\frac{1}{k}<X\leq\frac{1}{k-1}\right)=\lim_{m\to\infty}P\left(X>\frac{1}{m}\right)$$

For $\delta>0$ find $m_{\delta}$ such that $P\left(X>\frac{1}{m_{\delta}}\right)>P\left(X>0\right)-\delta$.

Observe that this is the same as $P\left(X\leq\frac{1}{m_{\delta}}\right)<P\left(X\leq0\right)+\delta$

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\epsilon_n=0$ you can find $n_{\delta}$ such that $n\geq n_{\delta}$
implies $\epsilon_{n}<\frac{1}{m_{\delta}}$ and consequently $P\left(X\leq\epsilon_{n}\right)\leq P\left(X\leq\frac{1}{m_{\delta}}\right)<P\left(X\leq0\right)+\delta$.

Comment: How do you know that $\sum_{k=2}^\infty P(\frac{1}{k}<X\leq\frac{1}{k-1})$ converges, i.e. it is equal to $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=2}^m P(\frac{1}{k}<X\leq\frac{1}{k-1})$?

Comment: Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges *by definition* if sequence $(s_m)$ converges where $s_m:=\sum_{n=1}^ma_n$. Have a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/831519/75923).